# Cohort Data transformation

Tags: r, transformation

I have the following data:

```
    signup_date purchase_date nbr_purchase
    2010-12-12             7            2
    2011-01-03             4            1
    2010-11-28             6            2
    2011-01-05            19            9
    2010-11-10            26            3
    2010-11-25            11            2
```

Where each row corresponds to a customer, signup_date is sign up date, purchase_date is number of days elapsed from sign up and first purchase, nbr_purchase is number of items purchased. I would like to carry cohort analysis and transform the data to look like:

```
cohort  signed_up  active_m0  active_m1  active_m2
2011-10 12345      10432      8765       6754
2011-11 12345      10432      8765       6754
2011-12 12345      10432      8765       6754
```

Cohort here is in “YYYY-MM” format, signed_up is the number of users who have created accounts in the given month, active_m0 – number of users who made first purchase in the same month as they registered, active_m1 – number of users who made first purchase in the following month, and so forth.

Comment: How are you defining months here. If a sign up was Jan 31 and purchase was Feb 1, is that the next month? Are months units of ~30 days? If would be nicer if the output your provided was correct for the same input data so we know when we get the right answer.

Comment: Sorry for the fictive output, but I have like 3M customers, so it hard to get correct output manually. I am considering 30 days for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input data in in the following format

```
dd<-structure(list(signup_date = structure(c(14955, 14977, 14941, 
14979, 14923, 14938), class = "Date"), purchase_date = c(7L, 
4L, 6L, 19L, 26L, 11L), nbr_purchase = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 
2L)), .Names = c("signup_date", "purchase_date", "nbr_purchase"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then you can do

```
dd$cohort <- strftime(dd$signup_date, "%Y-%m")
dd$interval <- paste0("active_m",(dd$purchase_date %/% 10) +1)

tt<-with(dd, table(cohort, interval))
cbind(tt, signed_up=rowSums(tt))
```

to get the data you need

```
        active_m1 active_m2 active_m3 signed_up
2010-11         1         1         1         3
2010-12         1         0         0         1
2011-01         1         1         0         2
```

note that here I used 10 day intervals rather than 30 day since you didn't have any purchase observations that were over 30 days from signup. So for your real data, change `%/% 10` to `%/% 30`.